# Why doesn't Selenium find the element here?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like help to know why selenium doesn't find the element, it finds the first one, but the second it doesn't find it, and when I look manually the element is there I don't know if it's something misconfigured or if it's a bug of selenium itself or if selenium does not load the element after it finishes loading the page, follow the code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
op = Options()
#op.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=op)
driver.get('https://br.betano.com/')
sleep(10)
e1 = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"INICIAR").click()
sleep(15)
e2=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/main/div/form/div[1]/input")
```

erro

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 102.0.5005
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 102.0.5005 google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\BPL\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\102.0.5005.61\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\BPL\OneDrive\Trabalho\bot_fan_tan\servidor.py", line 20, in <module>
    e2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/i/svg").click()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/i/svg"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x005AD953+2414931]
    Ordinal0 [0x0053F5E1+1963489]
    Ordinal0 [0x0042C6B8+837304]
    Ordinal0 [0x00459500+1021184]
    Ordinal0 [0x0045979B+1021851]
    Ordinal0 [0x00486502+1205506]
    Ordinal0 [0x004744E4+1131748]
    Ordinal0 [0x00484812+1198098]
    Ordinal0 [0x004742B6+1131190]
    Ordinal0 [0x0044E860+976992]
    Ordinal0 [0x0044F756+980822]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0081CC62+2510274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0080F760+2455744]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0063EABA+551962]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0063D916+547446]
    Ordinal0 [0x00545F3B+1990459]
    Ordinal0 [0x0054A898+2009240]
    Ordinal0 [0x0054A985+2009477]
    Ordinal0 [0x00553AD1+2046673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7551FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77007A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77007A4E+238]
```

Comment: error message points to xpath with svg (`{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/i/svg"}` ) but none of such xpath expressions mentioned in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to locate and getting `NoSuchElementException` you could use the below, there could be other reasons too, for `NoSuchElementException` those can only be solve by looking into the `HTML` source of the `element`. Try the below and let us know this does not solve your issue.

***Import***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

To wait for [**presence_of_element_located :**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located)

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath']")))
```

To wait for **[visibility_of_element_located](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) :**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")
```

To wait for **[element_to_be_clickable](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)** :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "element_link_text")))
```

**OR** *You can use* `javaScript`

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"yourXpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: the error still persists

Comment: Share the `HTML` source for this element, the timeout exception is because the element is not visible or present or could be any other reason, have you tried the other `wait` i mentioned above

Comment: <input placeholder="" type="text" name="Username" id="username" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="on" data-qa="input" aria-invalid="false" class="" data-v-7b5ef3c4="">

yes I tried all 3

Comment: There is no issue in your code may be the element is inside the iframe or something, i updated the answer please try using javascript

Comment: again it returned the same error


selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)

Comment: the code was like this
op = Options()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=op)
driver.get('https://br.betano.com/')
element=driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"INICIAR").click()
sleep(15)
element1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"username\"]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Comment: `element` should be `element1` in `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, but i didn't understand how to do it, because the second element doesn't work

Comment: The element you want to click is `element1` using `javascript` but in last line you have provided `element` that you already clicked. So you should change `element` to `element1` in last line

Comment: let me see if i understand, the code like this still doesn't work

element1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="username"]')
driver.execute_script(r'document.querySelector("#username").click();', element1)

Comment: and not like that either

element1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="username"]')
driver.execute_script(r'arguments[0].click();', element1)

Comment: I want  to see the complete `HTML` can you add it.?

Comment: I tried to put it here but it's too big, look at the site "https://br.betano.com/" because it's the site I'm trying

Comment: I am unable to access this site.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JHV5ke8NtOK9JCPY_Z3oXpNxzR-L3LBb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The error pointing the locator does not exist in your `code`